# grails pagination set page limit

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have 1000 records, with 10 records per page, means total 100 steps are displayed with 10 records on each step are available on my screen.

Now I want to set limit to show only 10 pages and when i clicked on 6 or 7th page it show another page say 11 , 12th. same function as available in goggle search.

code looks like below.

```
def aInstanceList = aCriteria.list(max: params.max?:10, offset: params.offset?:0, sort:params.sort, order: params.order) {
```

Can any one tell me how to achieve this in grails pagination.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of steps displayed by setting the 'maxsteps' parameter of pagination, which defaults to 10. That is the closest, that you would get with grails pagination tag. If you want something entirely different, try creating your own tag. Its not that hard..